# How do you change the GRUB2 username & password?

Tags: linux, centos, grub2, vagrant

I recently downloaded the official [centos/7 Vagrant Cloud VM](https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7). While trying to access its GRUB2 menu during a reboot via the <kbd>e</kbd> key, I ran into a prompt for a username + password.

[image: ss1]

I was unsuccessful in finding this referred to anywhere on the official page for this VM, in the [blog post announcing it](https://blog.centos.org/2018/05/updated-centos-vagrant-images-available-v1804-02/), nor in any of these git repos:

- [CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-build/vagrant](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-build/tree/master/vagrant)
- [lpancescu/sig-cloud-instance-build](https://github.com/lpancescu/sig-cloud-instance-build)

Perhaps I modified this at some point and no longer recall the username & password that was used to protect GRUB2's boot menu.

In either case, rather than hunt for this any further, how can I simply change the credentials in GRUB2 to whatever I want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you'll typically have access to root via `sudo` when you start up your Vagrant VM, you can simply log into it and become root like so:

```
$ vagrant ssh
$ sudo -Es
```

Once you're root you can reset the credentials to whatever you want in one of two ways.

### RHEL & CentOS 7.2+ & Fedora

Starting with RHEL & CentOS 7.2+ & Fedora there's a helper script/tool, `grub2-setpassword`, that's included which greatly simplifies the process to do this.

To use it you'd do the following:

```
$ grub2-setpassword
Enter password:
Confirm password:
$
```

Once you've done the above the password will automatically be set for you in this file: `/boot/grub2/user.cfg`:

```
$ cat /boot/grub2/user.cfg
GRUB2_PASSWORD=grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.5A95A11398D5DEAA9B205DCEA37E0FDCC069CF6D0C398E8C9FF2ED1D8DE072DDE1D916F955266C306AAC7CA62E0D29A7C6558F3B29E40008289DBE857B8354CE.DD410AA2E5D6495BA723147046B88B89A585656AF4298F07CBC93E7A4F73713A824AE1F3448F837809B6655861A1BA5F0FB615206470E4228E57F7BCF11442A3
```

You can look at how this file gets used by GRUB2 on CentOS based distros by looking for it in `/etc/grub.d` like so:

```
$ grep -l user.cfg /etc/grub.d/*
/etc/grub.d/01_users
```

Contents of that file:

```
$ cat /etc/grub.d/01_users
#!/bin/sh -e
cat << EOF
if [ -f \${prefix}/user.cfg ]; then
  source \${prefix}/user.cfg
  if [ -n "\${GRUB2_PASSWORD}" ]; then
    set superusers="root"
    export superusers
    password_pbkdf2 root \${GRUB2_PASSWORD}
  fi
fi
EOF
```

Ah so the default user will be 'root'. Good so if we were to reboot our VM and try using the credentials 'root' with the password we supplied to `grub2-setpassword`:

[image: ss2]

We can now get into the menu:

[image: ss3]

### Ubuntu 16.04+

On other distros that do not provide the script `grub2-setpassword` the process is a bit more involved, but not terrible.

#### 1. generate an encrypted password

You need to use the GRUB2 tool to encrypt your password:

```
$ grub-mkpasswd-pbkdf2
Enter password:
Reenter password:
PBKDF2 hash of your password is grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.465B5EE2D2F6A767304EB397D6D97C70BC38653F95AFE58B24F190D5DABB0143920F736C125B91FB9F298AFF3D0F8FBBFB8228D5C8C9DD371ADBB1044CC80BFC.52D87AFD47A5BE2D7B6CF755D26CD5F481557DBCF5E725ABA44BF003A2970D3F775E8657428EDC201D86A3DF07D7A8109AFD5764EA058BE94D840F42ED17C3E2
```

#### 2. Add password to GRUB2 config

and then take the output of that command, `grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.....`, and copy/paste it into a file.

```
$ cat /etc/grub.d/40_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.465B5EE2D2F6A767304EB397D6D97C70BC38653F95AFE58B24F190D5DABB0143920F736C125B91FB9F298AFF3D0F8FBBFB8228D5C8C9DD371ADBB1044CC80BFC.52D87AFD47A5BE2D7B6CF755D26CD5F481557DBCF5E725ABA44BF003A2970D3F775E8657428EDC201D86A3DF07D7A8109AFD5764EA058BE94D840F42ED17C3E2
```

**NOTE:** We're setting the username to 'root', it can be whatever you want. if you change it, be sure to change it on both lines (`superusers="root"` & `password_pbkdf2 root ...`).

#### 3. Rebuild GRUB2 `grub.cfg`

Now we need to regenerate our `grub.cfg`:

```
$ grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-130-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-130-generic
done
```

This will take all the contents of `/etc/grub.d` and incorporate it into a new `grub.cfg`. So our `40_custom` section of `grub.cfg` will go from this:

```
$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
...
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
...
```

To this:

```
$ cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
...
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

set superusers="root"
password_pbkdf2 root grub.pbkdf2.sha512.10000.465B5EE2D2F6A767304EB397D6D97C70BC38653F95AFE58B24F190D5DABB0143920F736C125B91FB9F298AFF3D0F8FBBFB8228D5C8C9DD371ADBB1044CC80BFC.52D87AFD47A5BE2D7B6CF755D26CD5F481557DBCF5E725ABA44BF003A2970D3F775E8657428EDC201D86A3DF07D7A8109AFD5764EA058BE94D840F42ED17C3E2
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
...
```

#### References

- [25.6. PROTECTING GRUB 2 WITH A PASSWORD](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sec-protecting_grub_2_with_a_password)
- [HOW TO PROTECT GRUB2 BOOTLOADER WITH PASSWORD IN RHEL/CENTOS 7](http://www.elinuxbook.com/how-to-protect-grub2-bootloader-with-password-in-linux/)
- [fedoraproject's wiki - GRUB2 - Setting a password for interactive edit mode](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Setting_a_password_for_interactive_edit_mode)
- [How to password protect your GRUB menu](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-password-protect-your-grub-menu/)